# Heat shock proteins in T cells of tumor microenvironment

Tags: cell-biology, immunology, cancer, immunosuppression

Analyzing human tumor [single-cell RNA sequencing (scRNA-seq)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_cell_sequencing#Transcriptome_sequencing_(scRNA-seq)) data, I found abundant expression of Heat shock protein (HSP) family genes in T cells. My literature review on "HSPs in T cells" brought a lot of papers. But all those papers are talking about how HSPs in **cancer cells** suppress anti-tumor immunity through different pathways. I do not particularly see much HSP expression in cancer cells though. Does that mean HSPs expression is not important on T cells or maybe it was not extensively studied from that point of view? Could somebody explain that from biological meaningfulness perspective, please?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I've made a few changes to your post, please check to make sure that I have not accidentally altered your intended meaning. In the future, please make sure you explain all acronyms and abbreviations the first time you use them — they are often ambiguous. Providing links that explain techniques and other relevant source material is also helpful. ——— In addition, can you tell us why your search didn't include "T-cell"? NB: if you are doing "Google" based searches then the "AROUND" operator can be very helpful e.g. `"HSP" AROUND(3) T-cell tumor microenvironment` ...

Comment: ... Also, this site works best if you make sure that each post contains a single clear well-focused (narrowly scoped) question — you appear to have more than one question and the last question is both unclear *(¶ What is the "that" you want biological meaning for?)* and potentially too broad. ——— I encourage you to take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details — this will help you get up to speed on this site's peculiarities and avoid pitfalls that can lead new users to have a poor experience here.

Comment: ok. thank you for the tips! should I ask a new question then?

Comment: You're welcome! It is best to [edit] this post so that is a single question and then move any additional questions into separate posts.